# Error: Firebase (2.2.6) INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED: listen() called twice for same path/queryId

Tags: firebase

I am using Firebase JavaScript client library and getting an error "**Error: Firebase (2.2.6) INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED: listen() called twice for same path/queryId**"

Actually, I am attaching 'child_added' event listener to a database reference to read messages of user with id 1.

e.g. - user/messages/1

After some time I detach the listener by calling "**ref.off()**" on the same reference.

Now when I try to attach the same listener again on the same reference, I get following error:

```
"Error: Firebase (2.2.6) INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED: listen() called twice for same path/queryId.
Hc@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.6/firebase.js:35:1651
J@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.6/firebase.js:35:1622
h.xf@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.6/firebase.js:185:287
Kh/this.O<.Xe@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.6/firebase.js:201:344
uf@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.6/firebase.js:118:55
gf.prototype.Ob@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.6/firebase.js:115:34
Vh@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.6/firebase.js:207:301
Y.prototype.Eb@https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.6/firebase.js:225:223"
```

Can somebody help me understand the reason for this error? Is the listener not getting detached or there is some other reason for the same?

Comment: Can you add the relevant code?

Comment: I have the same problem. Firing .off() but when I return right back to the action and set the .on(child_added) event again, i get the same internal assert failed error, as if I had not called .off (but I have, i've updated the data to check).

Answer (score 0):

remove .limitToLast(25) after firebaseRef